# SED Ends with does not work with string index

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting

Sample input is:

```
 3 TT 00670101J12SEP1629OCT16     6  OTP08100810+0300  DXB14351435+04001 73WCDIOYBMUKRHGLQNTVSEX     XX                                                           M                              00468673
"7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE," | sed "s/$,\{9\}\(.\{3\}\).*/\1,&/"
```

Sample output required is

```
7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE,C
```

if character from 170 onwards does not exists..

7518 is line number.. Its already developed but I am working on an extra requirement that if character from 170 onwards exists add to the end of row after the comma else take first character from previous token..

Comment: `$` is a meta character meaning end of pattern space, iff it's the last character in the pattern. Anywhere else it's literal `$`. In some versions of sed it will also be end of pattern space when it's logical the last part of a pattern, i.e: `abc\($\|def\)`

Comment: The real query will be something like this:

sed '/./=' MYTXTFILE.txt | sed '/./N; s/\n/ /' | sed -ne 's/ 3\s.\{70\}\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{25\}\).\{72\}\(.\{15\}\).*/\,\ \1,\2,\3 /p'|sed -e 's/\s//g' -e 's/VV/,V/g'

I want to change this so that if we don't have the forth token and third token ends with a comma, I should extract a substring from MYTXTFILE.txt say from 5th to 10th column index of the file and put it in the end.

Comment: The below works fine except that I am replacing the end with "test":

sed '/./=' RO.txt | sed '/./N; s/\n/ /' | sed -ne 's/ 3\s.\{70\}\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{25\}\).\{72\}\(.\{15\}\).*/\,\ \1,\2,\3 /p'|sed -e 's/\s//g' -e 's/VV/,V/g' -e 's/,$/,test/g'

However if I replace test with sub-string from say 5th index to 10th index of MYTXTFILE.txt, this does not work..

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the content from `RO.txt` and your expected output?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/(^.*,)(.{3})(.*)/\1\2\3\2/g' <<< "7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE,"
7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE,CDI
```

Or following if you want to preserve double quotes:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*,)(.{3})(.*)/"\1\2\3\2"/g' <<< "7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE,"
"7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE,CDI"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
$ sed 's/,\(...\)[^,]*/&,\1/2' input.txt
7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE,CDI,
```

It will replace the second match of `,` followed by three characters:

```
7518,32S,CDIYBMULKRQHTVNSE,
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#       ||||             ^ End of match
#       |^^^ Captured in \1
#       ^ Start of match
```